# Is it possible to get a different header.php on language switch with qtranslate?

Tags: plugin-qtranslate

the problem is that on home page I have a lot of code which is added through header.php and it is not amendable through admin panel. What I want to do is to switch header files on language switch. Whenever a user press on the language icon, lets say on the English language icon the header should also switch from `<?php get_header('mylanguage') ?>` to `<?php get_header('english') ?>` or etc. Is it possible to do like this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Following the codex about the [get_header function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header)

You must have an archive `header-de.php` in your template.

Create one for each language you have and adjust the `switch` accordingly.

```
<?php 
if(function_exists('qtrans_getLanguage')) {
    $lingo = qtrans_getLanguage(); 
    switch ($lingo) {
        case 'de':
            get_header('de');
            break;
        default:
            get_header();
            break;
    }
} else {
    get_header();
}
```

Comment: You don't event really need the switch.  `get_header` will fall back to `header.php` if `header-de.php` doesn't exist.